# C# - Single class to manage generic classes

Tags: c#

I have a base class `Database` and 2 classes deriving from this class, `MSSQLDatabase` and `SQLCEDatabase`.

I can use `Database.SetDatabase(new MSSQLDatabase())` then I am able to fetch the instance by using `Database.GetDatabase<T>()`, and as an example use `Database.GetDatabase<T>().Connect()`.

However I would like to know if there is a way I can specify the desired class for ex. `MSSQLDatabase` once, then just call `Database.Connect()` and have the `Database` class cast to the specified class?

Comment: What you ask is already available out of the box through the ADO.NET [Factory Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/factory-model-overview). You can already specify the provider by name and use the abstract base classes, eg DbConnection, DbCommand

Comment: _They include DbConnection, DbCommand, and DbDataAdapter and are shared by the .NET Framework data providers, such as System.Data.SqlClient and System.Data.OleDb._ Do you know if this will also work with SQL Compact Edition?

Comment: why would you want to cast to the specific class? Actually those two classes should just implement a common interface and should be **interchangable** without clients needing to be changed. There should be no code that relies on the reference beeing of a **specific** class. In fact it should be possible to replace the instance by e.g. `MyOwnDbClass`.

Comment: @SupertimeDeveloper all ADO.NET classes derive from the same base classes and interfaces. MySQLCommand, Sqlcommand, OracleCommand, all inherit from DbCommand. That allows ORMs like EF Core and microORMs like Dapper to work with any database

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain that's how things already work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that. However OP seems to not know anything about ADO.Net. Or for whatever reason wants to implement his/her own ORM.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Thank you for the response. Actually I just didn't know this already exists. So I will definitely be using it instead of trying to implement my own solution. Is there any specific keywords or resources I can google for to learn how to implement this? Or would "ADO.NET Factory Model Tutorial" be enough?... To be honest I am fairly new to implementing databases in my applications.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Never mind, I think I found what I needed. Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, you will have to think differently. `Database` should be a single class that would take in the constructor a parameter like an interface `IDb` and the `MSSQLDatabase` and `SQLCEDatabase` should implement the `IDb`.
Now you can call the  `new Database(new MSSQLDatabase())` once and from here you  can call `Database.Connect()` every time knowing that behind your code will work with `MSSQLDatabase`. With this approach you would use "Aggregation" instead of yours that is more like a "Composition".

Comment: Again, that's how things *already* work

Comment: Why do u assume that he wants to use what the framework already offers? Maybe he wanna learn and build something custom...

Comment: Because that's impossible without using what the framework offers. You can't put an interface on an already existing third-party class. Which means you'll have to use DbCommand/IDbCommand to return the connection or command from any custom methods. Even if you create a generic method, you *have* to specify a generic constraint to allow anyone else to use methods on that class. Unless you intend to rebuild everything from scratch, wrapping every single provider in your custom classes. You'd have to do a lot of work before you can even start using those custom classes.

Comment: Yes, u are right.... but because his question doesn't properly describe the context.... that is why I gave him a more general answer.